# Как подключить src исходник vue.js в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vue.js

Как можно подключить исходник приложения на Vue.js "SRC" в Visual Studio Code.
Добавил папку с проектом но при сборке компилятор не видит исходник.
Я новичок, поэтому буду признателен если распишите детально как это выполнить.

исходник: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/H8bJGe6zUctlIg